# Make query for every object in json using for or forEach

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

My problem is, I want to make INSERT query for every object from JSON using some loop, but I almost always got an error "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client".Can someone help?Tnx

```
const connection = require('./config');

module.exports.excel = function (req, res) {

    var _query = 'INSERT INTO excel (id, first_name, last_name) values ?';

    var jsonData = req.body;

    var values = [];

    function database() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            jsonData.forEach((value) => {
                values.push([value.id, value.first_name, value.last_name]);
                connection.query(_query, [values], (error, results) => {
                    if (error) {
                        reject(
                            res.json({
                                status: false,
                                message: error.message
                            }))
                    } else {
                        resolve(
                            res.json({
                                status: true,
                                data: results,
                                message: 'Excel file successfully created in database'
                            }))
                    }
                });

            });
        })

    }
    async function write() {
        await database();
    }

    write();
}
```

After I got JSON from my Angular 6 front I put req.body into jsonData and try with forEach to put every object("value" in this case) into query and write that into Excel file.

Comment: You can only send one `response` back to the client, right here you are sending one for each iteration inside `forEach`

Comment: You can only send one response based on one request. You’re sendimg multiple. That’s where your error is from. Instead you probably want to use ‘promise.all’ and return a response when all promises finish (or error out)

Comment: Ok, thx I`ll try

Answer (score 0):

You will have to wrap each `query` in a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and wait for all to complete before sending the `response` using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Not that `database()` is going to `throw` when one of the queries fail and you won't have any access to the resolved promises.

```
const connection = require('./config');

module.exports.excel = function(req, res) {
  const _query = 'INSERT INTO excel (id, first_name, last_name) values ?';

  const jsonData = req.body;

  function database() {
    return Promise.all(
      jsonData.map(
        value =>
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const values = [value.id, value.first_name, value.last_name]

            connection.query(_query, [values], (error, results) => {
              if (error) {
                reject(error.message);
                return;
              }
              resolve(results);
            });
          })
      )
    );
  }

  async function write() {
    try {
      const results = await database();
      res.json({
        status: true,
        data: results,
        message: 'Excel file successfully created in database'
      });
    } catch (e) {
      res.json({
        status: false,
        message: e.message
      });
    }
  }

  write();
};
```

Comment: Now, I don`t get an error for headers(tnx for that :)) but there is some other problem. For each query it writes a row from excel file but for each following it is upgraded to it. So for 3 rows from excel I get 6 rows in db.

Comment: first row id[1] first_name[1] last_name[1]...second row id[1] first_name[1] last_name[1] id[2] first_name[2] last_name[2]... third row id[1] first_name[1] last_name[1] id[2] first_name[2] last_name[2]  id[3] first_name[3] last_name[3]

Comment: Maybe to use forEach instead of map?

Comment: @juicySausage You can't, `Promise.all()` needs to get an array of Promises. Check the excel file, and add some console.log to see if you get multiple requests somehow

Comment: @juicySausage Or maybe you didn't clean the database before updating the code ?

Comment: Excel is fine and I clean db before every code run, but the problem is in vales.push because I have to clean that or something before every iteration?

Comment: @juicySausage Yes, i will update my answer, there is no need to save it just use the current values, check and let me know if it's good now

Comment: I put values.pop and it seems to work properly now. And sorry but I am new in this and I have one more question. If I want, in one promise send every, for example 10 rows(), how can I do that?

Comment: @juicySausage You can't because you have to wait for each `query` to complete, I don't know `sql` but if you know how to insert all of them in one query instead of one at a time you can do it

Comment: In my first code above I was do it(send everything in one query) just without forEach, I send all file at once. But my question is can I push "values" with 10 data and then send it to db?

Comment: @juicySausage You were doing it one at a time using the forEach, for each iteration you run a query, it wasn't all at once

Comment: const _query = 'INSERT INTO excel (id, first_name, last_name) values ?';

Comment: onst jsonData = req.body;
    var values = [];  jsonData.forEach((value) => {
        values.push([value.id, value.first_name, value.last_name]);
    }) connection.query(_query, [values], function (error, results, fields) { if (error) {}else {

Comment: Without promises and forEach and I use this values to send all in one query